# Can't retrieve user photos although permissions are granted

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to access a user's facebook album for embedding on her website but I can't get more than basic account information with the facebook graph api.

The current basic code looks as follows:

```
FB.api('/userid/albums', function(callback) {
   console.log(callback);
}

// it returns a data array of length 0, at least no error
```

I think that my app doesn't have enough permissions. In various tutorials, I see how people are setting what permission the app should ask for, e.g. photos. I can't seem to find this setting in the current design.

Comment: What permissions are you asking for? Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965146/fb-graph-api-permissions-arent-working ?

Comment: I'm asking for no permission at all, just using `FB.login();`. I don't know where to specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ask for the user_photos permission when the user is logged in using Facebook. More about permissions at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

```
   FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('Permission granted');
        } else {
       alert('Permission not granted');
       }
     },{scope:'user_photos',perms:'user_photos'});
```